# Pandas GroupBy Subtotals

Tags: python, pandas

So I have a dataframe containing a time series, like:

```
NAME, DATE, VACATION (True/False)
Eric, 1/1/12, False
Eric, 1/2/12, True
...
Bob, 4/2/12, True
Bob, 4/3/12, False
```

Basically what I need out is a dict or something I can template in Jinja2 with the following format

```
{'eric': 
    vacations: [1/2/12, ... ],
    subtotals: {
          '2012': {
                    'total': 1 
                    'perweek': [1, 0, 0, ... ] (LEN = 52, week numbers)
                    'perquarter': [1, 0, 0, 0] (LEN = 4)
                   },
          '2013': { ... }
     },
 'bob': ...
}
```

Basically I need to get subtotals of vacations per user per year broken down into total per year, per week, per quarter.....

Is there a quick way to do that and convert it into a dict so I could use Jinja2 to template it out?

I know I can do groupby, etc.... but I could only figure out how to do per week separated from per quarter, per year, all as different groupbys and then re-assembly them into a dict.

Is there a way to do all of that at once?

Currently I am doing the following...

```
perweek = df.groupby(['name', 'date'].count.resample('W').count
for i in perweek.iter
  add to dict

perquarter = df.groupby(['name', 'date']).count.resample.count
for i in perquarter.iter
  add to dict

peryear ... etc
```

Basically I group, then count, then resample on.. then iterate over those and add them to the dict.  Do the same thing for each of the resamples I want.  It works... I was just wondering if there was a way to do it without multiple iterators.

Comment: Well that's a lot of things that needs to be done. Did you try anything?

Comment: Yes.  I have a fair amount of it functioning or patched together using multiple groupbys and loops.  I was just trying to see if there was something I was missing... e.g a faster way to go through them using pivot tables or something.

Comment: We need to see the code so we can improve a bit if possible  :)

Comment: I can post it in a bit when I get somewhere I have access to it, but the pseudo code I can put above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a complex solution.

```
def get_vacation_info(x):
    vacations = sorted(x["DATE"][x["VACATION"]=="True"].tolist())
    df_x = pd.DataFrame(vacations, columns=["DATE"]).apply(pd.to_datetime)
    df_x["year"] = df_x.DATE.dt.year
    df_x["week"] = df_x.DATE.dt.weekofyear
    df_x["quarter"] = df_x.DATE.dt.quarter

    def get_subtotals(y):
        total = len(y)
        perweek = y["week"].value_counts().reset_index()
        weekindex = pd.DataFrame([i for i in range(1, 53)], columns=["index"])
        merged_week = pd.merge(weekindex, perweek, on=["index"], how="left").fillna(0).astype(int)
        perweek = merged_week["week"].tolist()

        perquarter = y["quarter"].value_counts().reset_index()
        quarterindex = pd.DataFrame([i for i in range(1, 5)], columns=["index"])
        merged_quater = pd.merge(quarterindex, perquarter, on=["index"], how="left").fillna(0).astype(int)
        perquarter = merged_quater["quarter"].tolist()
        return {"total": total, "perweek": perweek, "perquarter": perquarter}

    subtotals = df_x.groupby("year").apply(lambda y: get_subtotals(y)).to_json()

    return {"vacations": vacations, "subtotals": subtotals}  

result = df.groupby("NAME").apply(lambda x: get_vacation_info(x))
```

Comment: That's perfect.